# How to get Session ID of WebSocket Connection from the Client Side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I'm using vanilla WebSocket in my VueJS project, no socket.io or vue wrappers of it. Followed the explanation here, https://javascript.info/websocket, it works.

However, I need to access the id of the session made in the client side. I don't want to use socket.io or WebSocket plugins dedicated for VueJS.  I'd appreciate if someone would shed a light on that. Because I haven't figured it out yet.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://10.10.10.10:8080/dummy");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("onopen: ", e);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("onmessage data: ", event.data);
};
```